# Co-workers discussing their future employers

Tags: colleagues, exit-planning

In my current company, I have been in conversations with co-workers discussing with others about the next company they are going to join. They also discuss the interview calls and offers they received from other employers with each other.

Is that a good behavior to have discussion on such things? If not, then how should I counter such questions or counter having these discussions politely when I am about to leave?

**Edit**

I work for a private IT/BPO/KPO company in India. And this is my 4th workplace. Its a new state and city for me. But before this I never heard my ex-colleagues having such discussion.

Comment: Can you provide more info about your industry, country etc.? Depending on the industry, whether it's public/private sector etc, in some professions, it's not unusual for people to be so open about their next jobs.

Comment: Hello Vivek and welcome to the Workplace! What problem does this create for you? You don't manage these people and you're about to leave yourself; surely you'd like to talk to them to get some insight in the market? What am I missing here?

Comment: @rath I don't mind them having this discussion. And surely I would like to share insight on the vacancies elsewhere but asking how much I am offered bugs me

Comment: @VivekParekh Ah, I see. Totally agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can´t answer you specifically for India, so there my be a few things special to consider, that I did not cover here.
Basic work ethics to consider:

1. Are you on or off the clock? During your paid time you should not engage in any behavior that is not beneficial to your employer. On your time off, you are a private person and it is your absolute right to talk opportunities with other private persons.
2. Consider that, if a superior hears you are actively looking for new opportunities, he may consider firing you. Reasons are that he may not trust you now and that he want control the timing. He may also stop investing in you, so no more training and interesting projects. So be careful where and what info you spread.
3. Networking: On the other Hand, the best jobs ind the best companies are often never really on the market - and if they are, not for long. If you want to be offered such opportunities, you should build your network. If you stay in touch with former colleagues and give them tips and info's that helps them further their career, chances are they will return the favor.

At last, one word about talking salaries. You as an employee are at a serious disadvantage, as you have much less info on the salaries typically paid than you employer does. This is a big disadvantage in negotiations. It is your rightful interest to get the best possible price for your work, so talking and comparing salaries/offers with your colleagues helps all of you to get paid reasonably.

That is why, in Germany, the court ruled that an employer cannot forbid their employees to talk about their salaries and any contract stating otherwise is void.